# My button (EventListener) has limited click only

Tags: javascript

I am making a modal, so i made an example to make it simple, Program goes, when i click any button, a modal will show and the page too but it will only show specific page depends on the button, in this case, uno button is for page1, dos for page2 and tres for page 3.

everything goes where i wanted until i clicked all the button, Just to show you my problem, try clicking step by step from uno to tres, then click uno again, and that's it the pages does not change at all.

can you please figure out whats wrong with my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .btns {
            float: left;
        }
        .modal {
            display: none;
            background-color: aqua;
            float: right;
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        .page1 {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background-color: burlywood;
            margin: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .p1 {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .p2 {
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .p3 {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to Show Modal.</p>
    
    <div class="btns">
        <button class="myBtn" id="uno">uno</button>
        <button class="myBtn " id="dos">dos</button>
        <button class="myBtn "id="tres">tres</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal">
        Modal
        <div class="page1 p1">Page1</div>
        <div class="page1 p2">Page2</div>
        <div class="page1 p3">Page3</div>
    </div>
    
    <!--JS-->
    <script>
        var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
        var getModal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        var getPages = document.querySelectorAll('.page1');
        //console.log(getPages);

      
        for(let i=0; i<btn.length;i++ ){
            btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {showModal(); getId(); displayPage()}); 
        }

        function showModal(){
            getModal.style.display = "block";
        }

        function getId(){
            //console.log(event.target.id);
        }

        function displayPage(){
            var btnId = event.target.id;
            if(btnId == "uno"){
                getPages[0].style.display = "block";
            }else if(btnId == "dos"){
                getPages[1].style.display = "block";
            }else if(btnId == "tres"){
                getPages[2].style.display = "block";
            }
           
        }



    </script>
            
</body>
</html>
<html>
```

Comment: Sorry for unnecessary codes like function getId() and the class in div those p1 etc. , I forgot to delete them,

Comment: You are not hiding the other pages (when showing specified page), hence the last page `p3` is always on top, because of the `position:absolute;` in CSS.

Comment: I see, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not hiding the other modal pages when you trigger the display of one of them, therefore they are all displayed at the same time once you clicked all buttons, and the one with the highest `z-index` (in this case automatically determined by element order in the markup) overlays all others. Set the `display` property to `block` or `none` depending on whether it's the current modal page or not. You can also pass the index of the modal page to the `displayPage()` function, so you don't need those if statements to check for the button text.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
var getModal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var getPages = document.querySelectorAll('.page1');
//console.log(getPages);


for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    showModal();
    displayPage(i)
  });
}

function showModal() {
  getModal.style.display = "block";
}

function displayPage(pageIndex) {
  var btnId = event.target.id;
  getPages.forEach(function(modalPage, index) {
    getPages[index].style.display = index === pageIndex ? "block" : "none";
  });
}
```

```css
.btns {
  float: left;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  background-color: aqua;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

.page1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

.p1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.p2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.p3 {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to Show Modal.</p>

<div class="btns">
  <button class="myBtn" id="uno">uno</button>
  <button class="myBtn " id="dos">dos</button>
  <button class="myBtn " id="tres">tres</button>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  Modal
  <div class="page1 p1">Page1</div>
  <div class="page1 p2">Page2</div>
  <div class="page1 p3">Page3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question, im still noob at js what this means? getPages[index].style.display = index === pageIndex ? "block" : "none";  i got lost in = index === pageIndex? I have no idea what happened here.

Comment: It's a so-called ternary operator, a shorthand for `if (index === pageIndex) { getPages[index].style.display = "block"; } else {  getPages[index].style.display = "none"; }` so the left-hand side of the expression is the condition, the middle between question mark and colon is what happens when the condition is truthy and the right-hand side what happens when the condition is falsy.

Comment: Just one last question, is this ternary operator is a ecma script? By the way i use this trick in my project. And i understand how the flow works but i dont think i can make another of this in another situation.

Comment: Yes, it's a standard feature. Maybe this link will help you to get a better understanding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your *display* function. You must hide other pages when you want to show your new one. So add this function to your code.

```js
function hideAllPages(){
      getPages[0].style.display = "none";
      getPages[1].style.display = "none";
      getPages[2].style.display = "none"
   }           
}
```

then call it the first line of **displayPage** function.

```js
function 
   // Hide all pages first
   hideAllPages();

   var btnId = event.target.
   if(btnId == "uno") {
      getPages[0].style.display = "block"
   } else if (btnId == "dos") {
      getPages[1].style.display = "block"
   } else if (btnId == "tres") {
      getPages[2].style.display = "block"
   }
}
```

Also you can have some base structure for your code like:

- save *id* of pages or (better solution) get id of the page with **data-*** (Exp. data-page-id="uno") in html structure and retrieve it in *js* with listen to click event of page button click and use **getAttribute** function to see which page to show

I hope it helps :)